# Mouse Wheel scrolling in Screen session via Command Prompt/Powershell

Tags: command-line, ssh, powershell, gnu-screen, scrolling

I want to scroll via Mouse Wheel in a screen session I run in the Command Prompt or Powershell.

I already uncommented `termcapinfo xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@` in my .screenrc. I can scroll when I use PuTTY but it doesn't work in the Command Prompt or Powershell.

Is that just something that doesn't work in those programs or am I missing something? I prefer the Command Prompt because I created a .bat that automatically runs the ssh command.

Comment: Which Windows version, and which OpenSSH version (according to `ssh V`), are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro 22H2 19045.2965 and I'm using OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2